# how to start new activity from list activity within tabview

Tags: android

I am developing new application where I am using tab view as parent layout. I'm using TabHost to display 3 tabs within my application. Each of these tab has separate Activity containing a ListView. This is working fine. When you click on an item within the ListView it currently loads up a brand new Activity full screen leaving the TabHost. I'd like to load up these Activities within the TabHost. I want to retain the tabview after calling another activities from list view.

Thank you both for your response. Here is my code where I need your help.

################HelloTabWidget

//This class displays the tab view with 3 tab - Customer, Company and City.

```
    public class HelloTabWidget extends TabActivity {
    //public class HelloTabWidget extends ActivityGroup {
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            Resources res = getResources();


        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 
        TabHost.TabSpec spec; 
        Intent intent; 
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, CustomerTabView.class);
        spec = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("Customer")
                .setIndicator("Customer",
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_Customer))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, CompanyTabView.class);
        spec = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("Company")
                .setIndicator("Company",
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_Company))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, CityTabView.class);
        spec = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("City")
                .setIndicator("City", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_City))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

################CustomerTabView

//This class displays list view of customers names. On click on any item in the list, it should open customer detail page keeping same tabs view.

```
public class CustomerTabView extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String[] category = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.category_array);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.drawable.list_items,
                category));
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                //Need this logic where I can retain the tab view and call new activity class for customerdetails view.                 

                Intent intent; 
                intent = new Intent(CustomerTabView.this,
                        C_DetailActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

        });
    }
}
```

################C_DetailActivity

On click of any item from customertabview, this activity class gets call which shows details of the customer.

```
public class C_DetailActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText("This is the Customer Details view");
        setContentView(textview);
    }
}
```

After calling C_DetailActivity class, tab view disappear. I want to retain the main tab view. 
So need this logic where I can retain the tab view and call new activity class for customerdetails view

Comment: Keep it simple. I wouldn't do this.

Comment: Please post your code? This should be an easy implementation.

Comment: What else do you need? You have the intent?

Answer (score 1):

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
        String currentTag = tabHost.getCurrentTabTag();
        manager.destroyActivity(currentTag, true);
        manager.startActivity(currentTag, new Intent(this, newClass.class));
    }
});
```

Not tested, but something like this should work. If is doesn't I'll help you to fix it.

Comment: And does it work if you replace the OnItemClickListener with mine?

Comment: getLocalActivityManager will not work with ListActivity. Any idea how to retain tab view in detail page